# Placement of navigation bar buttons

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I am making an iPhone app and I have a UINavigationController as my root view and then UIVIewControllers from this. My Register button segues to the registration screen which automatically creates a Navigation Bar for me with the back button on the top left.

I have replaced the standard back button with my own image with the code below:

```
UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customBackButton.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 70);
[backButton setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popNavigationController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

I have also added a rightBarButtonItem to test but my issue is however that both these buttons arent in the corners of the screen as can be seen here.
[image]

Most other apps have the navigation bar buttons right in the corners as can be seen here from another app I found online as reference

[image]

I have tried to change the values here but that does nothing - the buttons stay where they are.

```
// Changing frames x-coordinate
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(-220, 0, 100, 70);
```

What do I need to do to set the buttons right in the corners of the navigation bar?

EDIT: If I use [backButton sizeToFit]; my image is displayed as below (the top grey bar is the navigation bar). Do I need to make the image the correct size?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change position of `UIBarButtonItem` you should use fake bar items as spacers

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -10;
```

Now you can set the array of bar items to achieve result needed

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[negativeSpacer, backBarButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of the buttons is too large. Remove this line:

```
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 70);
```

and then call

```
[backButton sizeToFit];
```

after

```
[backButton setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If this doesn't work, it's possible that there is white space baked into the PNG images themselves.

Comment: OK so I have to make the image the correct size? When I implement your solution and place the code as suggested, my button is HUGE and placed right in the middle of the navigation bar. I will edit my question to show yo what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cropping the image you're using (`customBackButton.png`) to get rid of any transparent margins? It looks like the image might be a little wide. Then you could decrease the width from 100px to something smaller and things should fit better.

Comment: Yes I have checked the image and there are no transparent edges on it at all. The image is cropped right to the edges of the hexagon shape